# How to tell what temporary tables are currently in scope in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, temp-tables

I often get the errors:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#foo'.

Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#foo', because it does not exist in the system catalog.
```

How do I know what temporary tables there are in scope?  They obviosly don't show up in SSMS like base tables do.

Answer (score 4):

You can check to see if the table exists before trying to perform a query on it.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#foo') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Brandon's answer...

In SSMS query window 1:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar int)
GO
CREATE TABLE ##bar (foo int)
GO
SELECT object_id('tempdb..#foo'), object_id('tempdb..##bar')
GO
```

In window 2:

```
SELECT object_id('tempdb..#foo'), object_id('tempdb..##bar')
```

`##bar` is visible in both sessions, as expected. `#foo` in the local session only.